# How to disable upside-down fliping of UIButton image when it's touched?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ios5

I seted an image for UIButton for "UIControlStateNormal" and if I press this button the image is shadowed and flips upside down for the time that i hold it.

Shadowing is ok, but how can I disable the fliping, if I dont want to set a custom image fo state "UIControlStateHighlighted" ?
Thanks for help

My code to making buttons is:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.tag=i;
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(xakt, yakt, a, b);
```

and after that I set the button image with `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` function. 
I included 2 images, first in normal state, the second in pressed state

[image: Normal state][image: pressed state]

Comment: I never saw flipped images... what's special about your button? Please post the code how you create the image and how you create the button.

Comment: please post the code. I don't understand what is actually your question goes?

Answer (score 2):

My observation of this behavior described above (image on button inverts when clicked) is limited to the following situations:

1. The image for the button is set using
   `- (void)setBackgroundImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` to with a state of `UIControlStateNormal`.
2. This condition is likely not required but the `imageOrientation` of the `UIImage` is `UIImageOrientationDown`.

Specifying the background image for two remaining control states should fix the problem.

```
UIButton *button = ...
UIImage *image = ...
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
// Specify same image for selected / highlighted states
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Note that:

```
[button setBackgroundImage:image
                  forState:UIControlStateNormal |
                           UIControlStateSelected |
                           UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to be using `- (void)setImage:(UIImage *)image forState:(UIControlState)state` on the `UIButton` instance.