# Issue with UIImageOrientation

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I have a veery interessting issue.
I want to use an UIImage as a backgroundImage of a UIButton. Before that I have to flip the image, becouse it is originaly in bat orientation. I do this like:

```
imageCopy =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageCopy.CGImage scale:1.0 orientation: UIImageOrientationDownMirrored];
```

The issue is. If I use this image, durring holding touched the button I can see the original not-mirrored image. It is flipping.
If I use the original not mirrorred image, then in every states (tached, nontouched etc.) I can see the original image. It is not flipping.

[image: Touched state][image: normal state]

Setting up the the good image for UIControlStateNormal and for the UIControlStateSelected don't help.
How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Also set your image for UIControlStateHighlighted

Comment: Did you not ask pretty much the same question some days ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8400287/how-to-disable-upside-down-fliping-of-uibutton-image-when-its-touched

Comment: Rayfleck: setting up UIControllsataeHighlighted doesn't help

TiLL: I did, but after that I found out new circumstances, and find to better to write a new post.